# CHMOD Folder and Files recursively but with different values

Tags: unix, chmod

Is there a way to recursively change the access rights of a specific folder to 755 and files to 644 Without using the find function and having sub-directories in that folder (don't want to change those) ?

Currently I'm using `chmod 755 -r folderName/`

using `find` I think its something like that :

```
find /specific_folder/ -type f -print | xargs chmod 644
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
chmod -R a=rX,u+w folderName
```

For CentOs the command is:

```
chmod -R a=rx,u+w folderName
```

But it will rewrite subdirectory permissions. 
As the consequence: you cannot do what you want with just `chmod`.

Comment: will that only work on files ? what about sub-directories .. i dont want to change their permissions

Comment: yes, it does work for sub-directories as well.

Comment: just tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: You mean doesn't work at all or what?

Comment: yes it doesn't work at all

Comment: @Tarek let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/958/discussion-between-akond-and-tarek)